# How to Get Server Last Updates Details along with Last Boot Time Rebooted Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, server

I need to get daily log that will look like that:

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledOn             LastRebooted          
------        -----------      --------      -----------             -----------               
SRV1...       Update           KB4049065     2/2/2018 12:00:00 AM    1/2/2019 10:00:00 AM 
SRV2...       Security Update  KB4048953     2/2/2018 12:00:00 AM    2/2/2019 09:00:00 AM
```

All achived is those Powershell codes:

This one **Display Updates by Date**:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering | Sort-Object -Property {$_.InstalledOn} -Descending
```

And that one is Show **Last Time Server Rebooted**:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
```

I try to combine both codes so it will display them in **The same table** but without success.

I even try [this](https://shellgeek.com/get-last-boot-time-of-computer-using-powershell/):

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering | Sort-Object -Property {$_.InstalledOn} -Descending | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
```

But all i got is Result that looks like that:

```
csname   LastBootUpTime
------   --------------
SRV1... 
SRV2...
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_quickfixengineering | Sort-Object -Property {$_.InstalledOn} -Descending | ForEach-Object -Begin {} -Process {    

    Write-Output ([PSCustomObject]@{
        Source = $_.CSName
        Description = $_.Description
        HotFixID = $_.HotFixID
        InstalledOn = $_.InstalledOn
        LastRebooted = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).LastBootUpTime
        })
    } -End {} | Format-Table
```

And if you want to keep the same style that you were trying to do this works for that.

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_quickfixengineering | Sort-Object -Property {$_.InstalledOn} -Descending | Select @{LABEL='SOURCE';EXPRESSION={$_.CSName}},Description,HotFixID,InstalledOn,@{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={(Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).LastBootUpTime}} | Format-Table
```

If you run ***Get-Member*** on the ***Get-WmiObject*** cmdlet you will see that you are trying to select a property that doesn't exist on those objects (***lastbootuptime***). Hence the null value you are getting.

**Running Get-Member:**

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_quickfixengineering | Sort-Object -Property {$_.InstalledOn} -Descending | gm
```

**Output of Get-Member:**

```
   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_QuickFixEngineering

Name                MemberType     Definition                                                                                                                                  
----                ----------     ----------                                                                                                                                  
PSComputerName      AliasProperty  PSComputerName = __SERVER                                                                                                                   
Caption             Property       string Caption {get;set;}                                                                                                                   
CSName              Property       string CSName {get;set;}                                                                                                                    
Description         Property       string Description {get;set;}                                                                                                               
FixComments         Property       string FixComments {get;set;}                                                                                                               
HotFixID            Property       string HotFixID {get;set;}                                                                                                                  
InstallDate         Property       string InstallDate {get;set;}                                                                                                               
InstalledBy         Property       string InstalledBy {get;set;}                                                                                                               
Name                Property       string Name {get;set;}                                                                                                                      
ServicePackInEffect Property       string ServicePackInEffect {get;set;}                                                                                                       
Status              Property       string Status {get;set;}                                                                                                                    
__CLASS             Property       string __CLASS {get;set;}                                                                                                                   
__DERIVATION        Property       string[] __DERIVATION {get;set;}                                                                                                            
__DYNASTY           Property       string __DYNASTY {get;set;}                                                                                                                 
__GENUS             Property       int __GENUS {get;set;}                                                                                                                      
__NAMESPACE         Property       string __NAMESPACE {get;set;}                                                                                                               
__PATH              Property       string __PATH {get;set;}                                                                                                                    
__PROPERTY_COUNT    Property       int __PROPERTY_COUNT {get;set;}                                                                                                             
__RELPATH           Property       string __RELPATH {get;set;}                                                                                                                 
__SERVER            Property       string __SERVER {get;set;}                                                                                                                  
__SUPERCLASS        Property       string __SUPERCLASS {get;set;}                                                                                                              
PSStatus            PropertySet    PSStatus {__PATH, Status}                                                                                                                   
ConvertFromDateTime ScriptMethod   System.Object ConvertFromDateTime();                                                                                                        
ConvertToDateTime   ScriptMethod   System.Object ConvertToDateTime();                                                                                                          
InstalledOn         ScriptProperty System.Object InstalledOn {get=if ([environment]::osversion.version.build -ge 7000)...
```